# When choosing an Image Size When Uploading a Photo in Safari for iOS - it removes the exif orientation data?

Tags: iphone

Im using the exif.js files to check the image orientation when selecting an image with a file input and then I display a thumbnail before the user can upload the image in a webapp.

When I do this with an original sized image then it is displayed right with the right orientation number. For example 3 for a landscape image.

BUT, if I select an image in my gallery and click at the bottom where you can select a different image size(small, medium,large, original) and I select one of them, then the image is displayed lying down and the orientation number is always 1, so it seams like it loses the exif information when it resize the image?
Is this a fact or Im I missing something?
Is there any way to get the right orientation number when selecting a smaller sized image?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've run into exactly this issue. Safari is indeed removing all the exif orientation data. Did you figure out what can we co with this or is there an open bug report for webkit?